# How to remove Windows-Network from Nautilus

Tags: samba, cifs

I am running 19.04 on machine with no other OS. Two things happened recently which seem to be interelated:

1) I was having problems with cups constantly adding a printer which couldn't be used to the printer list. I googled around and acting on info found I altered /etc/cups/cups-browsed.conf. The line I changed was from

> BrowseRemoteProtocols dnssd cups

to

> BrowseRemoteProtocols none

This only made it impossible to find my printer and so I reverted back to the original. Since then However, cups has stopped adding printers.

2) I have installed a new Fritz! home network and was playing around with the inbuilt NAS feature and trying to get it to work under Nautilus. To achieve this I installed Samba and cifs-utils. Now I have a Windows-Network and two other items under Nautilus "Other Locations" like this:
[image]

The two items STEVETUX-xxxxx and FRITZ-NAS are actually sub-directories in the Windows-Network directory and in the STEVETUX-xxxxx directory is the Print$ which still appears in my list of printers.

I cannot remove any of these "Networks" even as su. Can anybody tell me how to get rid of them?

Edit: I would also like to remove the Print at the bottom of my printer list. This too, cannot be removed in the usual way even as su. And it doesn't appear in the printer setup list so I can't remove it that way either.
[image]

Comment: Uninstall cifs-utils . You dont need it to connect to your nas if you know the path to nas share (smb://fritz-nas/sharename) . cifs-utils is required if you want to mount a cifs share without gvfs.

Comment: @cmak.fr Thanks. I have purged Samba and cifs-utils and rebooted. The only difference if that the STEVETUX-xxxxx network is no longer appearing under "Other Locations" in Nautilus.